# Variable leak in Makefile

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I've got two makefiles, which are included in one main makefile.
In the second makefile there's the following rule:

```
$(MAKEFILE2_OBJS): CFLAGS += -fPIC
```

As I've understood, when I write a rule like this one -fPIC will be added to CFLAGS only 
for MAKEFILE2_OBJS.
But when I compile MAKEFILE1_OBJS with implicit rule, CFLAGS has the -fPIC flag from the second makefile.

Why is it happening?

Main Makefile:

```
CC := gcc
LD := gcc
AS := nasm
DEPEND := ./depend.sh

CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror -I. -g -DNDEBUG -masm=intel
ASFLAGS += -f elf64
LDFLAGS +=

TARGET := arora
MODULES := utils stage1 stage2

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): stage1/arora-stage1 stage2/arora-stage2

SRCS :=
ERROR_FILES :=
OBJS :=
DEPS :=
OUTPUTS :=

include $(wildcard $(patsubst %,%/*.mk,$(MODULES)))

OBJS += $(SRCS:.c=.o)
DEPS += $(SRCS:.c=.d)
OUTPUTS += $(OBJS) $(DEPS) $(TARGET)

include $(DEPS)

%.d: %.c
    $(DEPEND) `dirname $*` $(CFLAGS) $*.c > $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OUTPUTS)
```

Makefile1:

```
STAGE1_ASM_SRCS := $(wildcard $(DIR)/*/*.s)
STAGE1_ASM_OBJS := $(STAGE1_ASM_SRCS:.s=.o)

STAGE1_C_SRCS := $(wildcard $(DIR)/*/*.c)
STAGE1_C_OBJS := $(STAGE1_C_SRCS:.c=.o)
STAGE1_C_DEPS := $(STAGE1_C_OBJS:.o=.d)
STAGE1_SRCS := $(STAGE1_ASM_SRCS) $(STAGE1_C_SRCS)
STAGE1_OBJS := $(STAGE1_ASM_OBJS) $(STAGE1_C_OBJS)

SRCS += $(STAGE1_C_SRCS)
ERROR_FILES += $(wildcard $(DIR)/*/*_errors.hx)
OUTPUTS += $(patsubst %,$(DIR)/%, linker_script.lds stage1.elf stage1_exec.bin stage1_data.bin stage1_main.bin arora-main-overwritten arora-exec-free-space-overwritten arora-stage1 original-definitions original-definitions.h) $(STAGE1_ASM_OBJS)

STAGE1_INCLUDE_PATH := $(DIR)

$(STAGE1_C_OBJS) $(STAGE1_C_DEPS): CFLAGS += -fno-stack-protector -nostdlib -I$(STAGE1_INCLUDE_PATH)

# hack
include $(DIR)/original-definitions

.PHONY: $(DIR)/stage1
$(DIR)/stage1: $(DIR)/arora-stage1 $(DIR)/arora-main-overwritten $(DIR)/arora-exec-free-space-overwritten $(DIR)/original-definitions $(DIR)/original-definitions.h

$(DIR)/original-definitions.h: $(DIR)/original-definitions $(DIR)/create_original_definitions_header.sh
    $(lastword $^) $< > $@

$(DIR)/original-definitions: $(DIR)/arora-original $(DIR)/extract-definitions.sh
    $(lastword $^) $< > $@

$(DIR)/arora-stage1: $(DIR)/stage1_main.bin $(DIR)/stage1_exec.bin $(DIR)/stage1_data.bin $(DIR)/arora-original
    cat $(lastword $^) > $@ && dd if=$< of=$@ bs=c seek=$(ARORA_MAIN_FILE_OFFSET) conv=notrunc && dd if=$(word 2, $^) of=$@ bs=c seek=$(ARORA_EXEC_FREE_SPACE_FILE_OFFSET) conv=notrunc && dd if=$(word 3, $^) of=$@ bs=c seek=$$(($(ARORA_EXEC_FREE_SPACE_FILE_OFFSET) + $$(wc -c $(word 2, $^) | awk '{print $$1}'))) conv=notrunc && chmod +x $@

$(DIR)/arora-main-overwritten: $(DIR)/arora-original $(DIR)/stage1_main.bin
    dd if=$< of=$@ bs=c skip=$(ARORA_MAIN_FILE_OFFSET) count=$$(wc -c $(lastword $^) | awk '{print $$1}')

$(DIR)/arora-exec-free-space-overwritten: $(DIR)/arora-original $(DIR)/stage1_exec.bin
    dd if=$< of=$@ bs=c skip=$(ARORA_EXEC_FREE_SPACE_FILE_OFFSET) count=$$(wc -c $(lastword $^) | awk '{print $$1}')

$(DIR)/arora-data-free-space-overwritten: $(DIR)/arora-original $(DIR)/stage1_exec.bin $(DIR)/stage1_data.bin
    dd if=$< of=$@ bs=c skip=$$(($(ARORA_EXEC_FREE_SPACE_FILE_OFFSET) + $$(wc -c $(word 2, $^) | awk '{print $$1}'))) count=$$(wc -c $(lastword $^) | awk '{print $$1}')

$(DIR)/stage1_main.bin: $(DIR)/stage1.elf
    objcopy -j .arora_main -O binary $^ $@

$(DIR)/stage1_exec.bin: $(DIR)/stage1.elf
    objcopy -j .arora_exec_free_space -O binary $^ $@ 

$(DIR)/stage1_data.bin: $(DIR)/stage1.elf
    objcopy -j .arora_data_free_space -O binary $^ $@

$(DIR)/stage1.elf: $(STAGE1_OBJS) utils/libpluginutils.a $(DIR)/linker_script.lds
    $(LD) $(STAGE1_OBJS) utils/libpluginutils.a -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) -ldl -nostdlib -T $(lastword $^)

$(DIR)/linker_script.lds: $(DIR)/linker_script.lds.template
    echo stage1_main will be at $(ARORA_MAIN_ADDRESS), the exec will be at $(ARORA_EXEC_FREE_SPACE_ADDRESS), the data will be after the exec. && sed s/ARORA_MAIN_ADDRESS/$(ARORA_MAIN_ADDRESS)/ $^ | sed s/ARORA_EXEC_FREE_SPACE_ADDRESS/$(ARORA_EXEC_FREE_SPACE_ADDRESS)/ | sed s/ARORA_DATA_LOADING_FREE_SPACE_ADDRESS/$(ARORA_DATA_LOADING_FREE_SPACE_ADDRESS)/  > $@
```

Makefile2:

```
DIR := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

STAGE2_SRCS := $(wildcard $(DIR)/*/*.c)
STAGE2_OBJS := $(STAGE2_SRCS:.c=.o) $(DIR)/overwritten/main-overwritten.o $(DIR)/overwritten/exec-free-space-overwritten.o $(patsubst %.s, %.o, $(wildcard $(DIR)/*/*.s))
STAGE2_DEPS := $(STAGE2_OBJS:.o=.d)

SRCS += $(STAGE2_SRCS)
ERROR_FILES += $(DIR)/stage2_errors.hx

OBJS += $(DIR)/overwritten/main-overwritten.o $(DIR)/overwritten/exec-free-space-overwritten.o
OUTPUTS += $(DIR)/stage2.so $(DIR)/overwritten/exec-free-space-overwritten.h $(DIR)/overwritten/main-overwritten.h $(DIR)/arora-stage2

.PHONY: $(DIR)/stage2
$(DIR)/stage2:  $(DIR)/arora-stage2

$(DIR)/arora-stage2: stage1/arora-stage1 $(DIR)/stage2.so
    cat $^ > $@ && chmod +x $@

$(DIR)/stage2.so: LDFLAGS += -shared
$(DIR)/stage2.so: $(STAGE2_OBJS) utils/libpluginutils.a
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

$(STAGE2_OBJS): CFLAGS += -fPIC

$(DIR)/overwritten/main-overwritten.o: stage1/arora-main-overwritten
    objcopy -F elf64-x86-64 -B i386 -I binary $^ $@

$(DIR)/overwritten/exec-free-space-overwritten.o: stage1/arora-exec-free-space-overwritten
    objcopy -F elf64-x86-64 -B i386 -I binary $^ $@

$(DIR)/overwritten/data-free-space-overwritten.o: stage1/arora-data-free-space-overwritten
    objcopy -F elf64-x86-64 -B i386 -I binary $^ $@

$(DIR)/overwritten/main-overwritten.h: $(DIR)/overwritten/main-overwritten.o $(DIR)/create_objcopy_header.sh
    $(lastword $^) $< > $@

$(DIR)/overwritten/exec-free-space-overwritten.h: $(DIR)/overwritten/exec-free-space-overwritten.o $(DIR)/create_objcopy_header.sh
    $(lastword $^) $< > $@

$(DIR)/overwritten/data-free-space-overwritten.h: $(DIR)/overwritten/data-free-space-overwritten.o $(DIR)/create_objcopy_header.sh
    $(lastword $^) $< > $@
```

Comment: That is odd. Can you give us a minimal complete makefile that gives this behavior? That is, can you pare down your makefiles, cut out as much as you can while still preserving this behavior, and post what's left?

Comment: That is not a minimal makefile that illustrates the problem; at least 50% of the material in it is superfluous for a minimal reproduction.  (For example, the dependency handling is not minimal; or, if it is, needs to be explained why it is crucial to reproducing the problem, and you'll need to show the contents of the dependency handling code.)  You also need to show two files: the main makefile and one included file.  We can't divine what you are doing.

Comment: Main make -  http://pastebin.com/zhyVwHJc  Make 1 -http://pastebin.com/BtuBTEM6 Make 2 - http://pastebin.com/LgMwgFPn

Comment: @Jah, please include the content in the question itself, not pastebin (don't worry, SO can afford a few extra bytes).

Comment: With GNU make, you can do a `make --debug=vvv` to get more information about which files it's considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU make reads the entire Makefile (and all included Makefiles) into memory before it starts evaluating the rules. The variables in the commands of a rule are expanded when the rule is executed, not when it is read. See the following example:

```
VAR = aaa

all:
    @echo $(VAR)

VAR += bbb
```

"make" produces the output "aaa bbb", because when the "all" rule is executed, $(VAR) has that value.

If a Makefile includes other files, everything is treated as one large Makefile.